# Player join in game table react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to create a table with some players, if I join the table my username should be in below of the screen like in another games. Likewise for other players!

What should I do for this.

```
export const GameStart = (props) => {
  const params = useParams();
  const gameID = params.gameID;
  const { isConnected, client, occupants } = useGameValue();

  const ourTeam = occupants?.findIndex((p) => p.nickname == client.nickname);

  console.log(ourTeam);

  const startGame = () => {
    client.start(gameID);
  };

  const playerIndex = occupants
    .filter((o) => !o.inactive)
    .findIndex((o) => o.nickname === client.nickname);


  const getPlayerStyle = (index) => {
    console.log("condition player index ", playerIndex, index);
    if (index === playerIndex) {
      const rotate = `rotate(0deg) translate(197px)`;
      console.log("if condition", rotate);
      return {
        transform: `${rotate}`,
      };
    } else {
      const angle = 360 / occupants.length;
      const rotate = occupants.length - index;
      const rotation = `rotate(${angle * rotate}deg) translate(197px) `;

      return {
        transform: `${rotation}`,
      };
    }

  };

  
  const playerCount = (players) => {
    return players === 1
      ? "count-1"
      : players === 2
      ? "count-2"
      : players === 3
      ? "count-3"
      : players === 4
      ? "count-4"
      : players === 5
      ? "count-5"
      : players === 6
      ? "count-6"
      : "";
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!client.nickname && isConnected) {
      client.nickname = prompt("enter nickname");
      client.join(gameID, null, client.nickname);
    }
  }, [isConnected]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(occupants, "occupants");
  }, [occupants]);

  return (
    <div className="gameStart">
      <h2>Game</h2>
      {occupants && (
        <div className="table">
          <div
            className={`players ${playerCount(occupants.length)}`}
            style={{ "--rotation-xtra-turns": `${playerIndex}` }}
          >
            {occupants.map((data, index) => {
            return (
                <div
                  className={`player`}
                  style={getPlayerStyle(index)}
                  key={index}
                >
                  {data.nickname}
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
      <button onClick={startGame}>Start Game</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is what I tried but its not working, What is not working is if I joined a new player in another device my previous user also in the same bottom space where my user place.

I want to know how is it happening, Can anyone modify and give it to me?

Comment: Hi, please read how to ask a question: you should always include the code that you tried! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Kokodoko  I added the component I made, can you look at it?

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple example with a function that puts a player with a certain name ("jan" in this case) at the bottom of the list. In this example I call the sort function with a button, but you can call it anytime you want. You have to replace "jan" with the actual username of the user.

```js
function Example() {
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState(["wim", "henk", "jan", "piet"]);
  
  const sortPlayer = () => {
    const newPlayerList =  [...players].sort((a,b) => {
      return (a === "jan")
    })
    setPlayers(newPlayerList)
  }

  const playerElements = players.map(p => {
        return <div key={p}>{p}</div>
    }
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={sortPlayer}>Sort JAN to bottom</button>
      <div>
        {playerElements}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: No its not working as expected. What should I do?

Comment: It's not really clear from your code where you are trying to put the current player name at the bottom of the table. It would help if you reduce your code to a minimal reproducible example.